# Can't open url with requests and urllib2

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I try to access `https://www.collinsdictionary.com/browse/english/words-starting-with-a` with python `requests`, but get `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))`.

I tried with `urllib2.urlopen`, but I got different html from what I see in browser (there is no `<ul class="columns2 browse-list">`).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Set a user-agent. `headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}` (picked at random from a google search) and `a = requests.get('https://www.collinsdictionary.com/browse/english/words-starting-with-a', headers=headers) `

Comment: I found that from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506092/python-requests-get-always-get-404/47506205#comment81981070_47506205) answer and further discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the website reject the get request of requests because of the default user-agent python use, you should set customized User-Agent to act as if you come from browser, User-Agent below is just an example to get the browser user agent for more current version google search my useragent

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get("https://www.collinsdictionary.com/browse/english/words-starting-with-a",headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the following code I do get the page you seem to want:

```
import urllib2
page =urllib2.urlopen("https://www.collinsdictionary.com/browse/english/words-starting-with-a")
print page.read()
```

it does contain `<ul class="columns2 browse-list">`