# Why is my login not working with Python Requests?

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I've been trying to login for the past couple days using Python Requests and have been having issues.

Here is my code:

```
import requests

LOGINURL = "https://admin.neopets.knetik.com/admin/login"
PROTECTEDPAGE = "https://admin.neopets.knetik.com/admin/order_summary/list"

payload = {
    "_target_path": "https://admin.neopets.knetik.com/admin/dashboard",
    "_username": "***",
    "_password": "***",
    "_remember_me": "on",

}

with requests.session() as session:
     post = session.post(LOGINURL, data=payload)
     response = session.get(PROTECTEDPAGE)
     print(response.text)
```

I'm sure I have all the parameters needed. I've tried searching for hidden_inputs and the only one I encountered was the "_target_path".

Any idea what I may be missing?

Comment: have you looked into `requests` auth built-ins?

Comment: @aws_apprentice: those are only helpful if the site uses Basic or Digest authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login page is pretty straightforward, but you are posting to the wrong URL.

The URL you are posting to serves the login form, but it does not accept any login credentials. The `<form>` tag tells you where to send those to:

```html
<form action="/admin/admin_login_check" ... method="POST">
```

The `action` attribute is a relative URL pointing to were you need to send your POST data.

Use *that* path as the login URL:

```
LOGINURL = "https://admin.neopets.knetik.com/admin/admin_login_check"
PROTECTEDPAGE = "https://admin.neopets.knetik.com/admin/order_summary/list"

payload = {
    "_target_path": "https://admin.neopets.knetik.com/admin/dashboard",
    "_username": "***",
    "_password": "***",
    "_remember_me": "on",

}

with requests.session() as session:
     post = session.post(LOGINURL, data=payload)
     response = session.get(PROTECTEDPAGE)
     print(response.text)
```

Some implementations want you to send a `GET` to the form page first, to establish a session cookie, however. The page doesn't use any CSRF protection, so you don't have to load the form to parse out that information.

Since these pages use HTTPS, you may also want to pass along the original form URL as a `Referer` header (It is commonly filtered out for HTTP or when traversing domains, as a security and privacy measure), the site may be using that as an additional measure against automated logins:

```
FORMURL = "https://admin.neopets.knetik.com/admin/login"
LOGINURL = "https://admin.neopets.knetik.com/admin/admin_login_check"
PROTECTEDPAGE = "https://admin.neopets.knetik.com/admin/order_summary/list"

payload = {
    "_target_path": "https://admin.neopets.knetik.com/admin/dashboard",
    "_username": "***",
    "_password": "***",
    "_remember_me": "on",

}

with requests.session() as session:
    session.get(FORMURL)
    post = session.post(LOGINURL, data=payload, headers={'Referer': FORMURL})
    response = session.get(PROTECTEDPAGE)
    print(response.text)
```

If that still doesn't work, the server is employing other robot-sniffing techniques. See [python requests.get always get 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506092/python-requests-get-always-get-404/47506205#47506205) for an overview of what kind of strategies you can follow if you really want to push this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed the LOGINURL to the one you mentioned. However, I'm still getting content from the login page when using print(response.text). If the login was successful, wouldn't I be getting content from my PROTECTEDPAGE URL?

Comment: @JohnDoe probably. Check the `response.history` attribute to see if you have been redirected. I’d add a GET request for the login page first, before the POST

Comment: @JohnDoe: that said I noticed I had made a copy and paste error and had not actually corrected the value of LOGINURL

Comment: WOW! The script works! Thanks so much! I knew I was missing something. So much frustration has been alleviated.