# Python: requests post login not succeed

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, web-crawler

Problem:
I tried to login with request.post for having the extra information in the part "preise", but soup.select("div[id*='preise']") always returns me the result which indicate login is not succeed.

```
payload = {
"username": "email",
"password": "password",
"rememberMe": True
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post("https://www.xxx", data=payload)
    print(s.cookies)
    response = s.get("https://www.xxx/yy")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content.decode("utf8"))
    print(soup.select("div[id*='preise']"))
```

The cookieJar looks like below:

```
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie msid=5d7cbf9f-43b2-43dc-9f6a-c766c2f4e805 for www.xxx>]>
```

I tried:

1. adding some **headers**, but I didn't understand what I should add exactly, so it is not working
2. doubt if the login url is not the real login url, (reference: [Why is my login not working with Python Requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419755/why-is-my-login-not-working-with-python-requests)), but I couldn't find any other url possible.
3. tried to print cookiejar to check if login is succeed, which indeed returns some value. Thus I am really confused why I could not have the tag correctly.
4. I know that I could retrieve the correct result using selenium, but I still wonder if this issue could be solved with only request.
5. Tried with solution of @Tobias P. G
6. Tried with personal cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of steps made this possible for me:

1. Copy headers from the login post on the website
2. Copy the encrypted password from the post on the website

Both done by using the developer tool and copying the information from the post request found under network. If you are unsure how to do that please ask and I will provide a brief introduction.

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()

headers = {
    'Host': 'www.xxx',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'da,en;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Content-Length': '70',
    'Origin': 'https://www.xxx',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://www.xxx/yy',
    'Cookie': 'cookie', # replace 'cookie' with those from the manual post request
}

payload = {
    "username": "email",
    "password": "password", # Copy the encrypted version from the manual post request
    "rememberMe": "true"
}

url = 'https://www.xxx/yy'

r = s.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(r.reason)

p = s.get('https://www.xxx/yy')

print(p.content)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I didn't manage to have the correct tag by following your step, I updated a photo with the information from the post request found under network and my code, when I print(r.reason) it returns Internal Server Error, I don't know if it is normal.

Comment: You need to copy your personal cookie as well

Comment: Hi, I tried with the entire request header copied from network with my cookies this time, but it still not working, I updated into #6, thanks in advance

Comment: The r.reason should give OK, so something is wrong with the headers and/or payload. Are you sure that the "==" are a part of the password ?

Comment: indeed, I missed one letter for encrypted version password, thank you so much now it works. Should I do something like s.close() in the end for closing the session ?