# Why is my PDF have the headers['content-type'] as 'text/html; charset=utf-8'?

Tags: python, pdf, python-requests

When downloading a pdf file from it's url I am observing a `headers['content-type']` as `'text/html; charset=utf-8'` when I need 'application/pdf'. Why is this doing it even when I am setting the Headers content-type?

Code example:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from pprint import pprint

file = 'url.pdf'
username = 'myusername'
password = 'mypassword'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/pdf', 'User-Agent': 'myUser-Agent'}
pdf_fname = 'new.pdf'

resp = requests.get(
    file, headers=headers, 
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password),
    proxies=proxyDict
)

with open(pdf_fname,'wb') as f:
    f.write(resp.content)

pprint(resp.headers['content-type'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GET` requests do not have a content body, so have no need for a `Content-Type` header. Setting the header there is meaningless. HTTP servers generally will ignore the header on any GET requests they receive.

The header you observe is set by the HTTP server you contacted, and if the data you receive from the server is a PDF file, so a response with an incorrect Content-Type header, then that's entirely on the server, not on your code or on `requests`. Just ignore the header, or contact the administrators of the site you are contacting to ask them to correct the error.

However, if the server is actually sending you HTML, then you may want to save that HTML somewhere and open it in a browser to see what the server is trying to tell you. It may be a specific error message or login page. We can't tell you if this is the case here or not, we simply don't know how *this specific* website is designed to operate.

Also see [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506092/python-requests-get-always-get-404/47506205#47506205) that covers troubleshooting `requests` HTTP requests which differ from how a web browser is being treated for the same URLs.