# Unable to find div class on page

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am unable to find the div class in the following code.

The url is the following:

https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/usa/nba/los-angeles-lakers-miami-heat-IqLamQfL/#over-under;1

The code I have is as follows:

```
html_doc = urllib.request.urlopen(new_url).read()
odds_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
table_header = odds_soup.find_all('div', {'id' : "odds-data-table", 'class' : 'bt-2'})
list = []
table_containers = []
for tag in table_header:
    table_containers += tag.find_all('div', {'class' : 'table-container'})
```

But the code only returns an empty list for table_containers. I am not sure why, and would really appreciate some help.

On inspection of the website, it looks like this:

[image: web page source]

Comment: Try changing your parser to `html5lib` do a `pip install html5lib` and I think also it is recommended to use `requests` instead of `urllib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you cannot find it cause your `table_header` doesn't find anything and the reason you're not getting anything from your `table_header`  is because you're having a `404` status code. You can check your status code by just doing a `.status_code` and print it.

Source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404#:%7E:text=The%20HTTP%20404%2C%20404%20Not,server%20could%20not%20find%20what)

> The HTTP 404, 404 Not Found, 404, 404 Error, Page Not Found, File Not
> Found, or Server Not Found error message is a Hypertext Transfer
> Protocol (HTTP) standard response code, in computer network
> communications, to indicate that the browser was able to communicate
> with a given server, but the server could not find what ...

I made some modifications on your code and printed out the `status code` and it says `404`. For the solution on why it is getting a `404` `status code` You might want to take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506092/python-requests-get-always-get-404) or probably you can just use `selenium` as one of the answers. Good luck!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/usa/nba/los-angeles-lakers-miami-heat-IqLamQfL/#over-under;1"

html_doc = requests.get(link)
print(html_doc.status_code)
odds_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc.content, 'html5lib')

table_header = odds_soup.find('div',{"id":"odds-data-table"})


'''
list = []
table_containers = []
for tag in table_header:
    table_containers += tag.find_all('div', {'class' : 'table-container'})
'''
```

Output:

```
404
[Finished in 2.1s]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select them like:

```
soup.find_all("div", class_="table-header-light odd first")
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to use selenium for this and pass to BS4. Then .append() to your list
or print it.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/usa/nba/los-angeles-lakers-miami-heat-IqLamQfL/#over-under;1')
odds_soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source , 'html.parser')
table_header = odds_soup.find_all("div", class_="table-header-light odd first")
for tag in table_header:
    print(tag)
```

Displays

```
<div class="table-header-light odd first"><strong><a href="" onclick="page.togleTableContent('P-201.50-0-0',this);return false;">Over/Under +201.5 </a></strong><span class="avg chunk-odd-payout"></span><span class="avg chunk-odd nowrp"></span><span class="avg chunk-odd nowrp"></span><span class="odds-cnt">(0)</span><span class="odds-co"><a class="more" href="" onclick="page.togleTableContent('P-201.50-0-0',this);return false;">Compare odds</a></span></div>
```